# variable outside Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I uploaded a json file using Ajax (with vanilla JS).

```
{
  "list": [
    {"name": "Egzekutor", "date": "19.04.2017, 12:32:57"},
    ...
  ]
}
```

Now, using addEventListenera, I can change "date" for the current one. Everything works, but I want to save changes in a file. The problem is when I try to use a variable with JSON.stringify(list) in PHP file, because my variable is not seen outside Ajax part. What can I do to use this variable?

Comment: Very unclear. Post more relevant code in the right order, thnx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the JSON variable in PHP you can use this function: [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php).

It lets you access the properties this way:

```
$json_obj = json_decode($json_string);
$json_obj->{'property_name'}; //
```